# SSRS: How to Group My Categories to Different Rows?

Tags: reporting-services

I'm creating SSRS report that needs to be grouped by names.

I need my table to be grouped by names so I have a table like this:

### MachineName|Memory %|CPU %|

Machine1|10|20|

Machine2|23|23|

Machine3|30|31|

Machine4|10|20|

Machine5     |  23       | 23    |

Machine6     |  30       | 31    |

Machine7     |  10       | 20    |

Machine8     |  23       | 23    |

Machine9     |  30       | 31    |

I need Machine1, Machine2, Machine 4, Machine 5 to be in category Production like this and Machine3, Machine 6 to be Development, and the rest to be to Stage environment.

### | Memory %  | CPU %  |

---

### Production

Machine1     |  10       | 20    |

Machine2     |  23       | 23    |

Machine4     |  10       | 20    |

Machine5     |  23       | 23    |

---

### Development

Machine3     |  30       | 31

Machine6     |  30       | 31

---

### Stage

Machine7     |  10       | 20    |

Machine8     |  23       | 23    |

Machine9     |  30       | 31    |

How do I do this in SSRS report?

I'm thinking of nested iif statement like this for each row under each category. For instance, for production category, I'll have a query like this:

```
IIF(Fields!MachineName.Value="Machine1",
    "Machine1",
     IIF(Fields!MachineName.Value="Machine2",
        "Machine2",
       IIF(Fields!MachineName.Value="Machine4",
        "Machine4",
       IIF(Fields!MachineName.Value="Machine5",
        "Machine5",0

     )
)
```

But this doesn't work.

Comment: Is the category stored in your table? If not, it should be.

Comment: Is there another alternative? What if I have like 100 MachineNames that I need to categorize?

Answer (score 0):

Add this into your sql select query and use the defined category as row group:

case MachineName
  when 'Machine1' then 'Production' 
  when 'Machine2' then 'Production'
  when 'Machine4' then 'Production'
  when 'Machine5' then 'Production'
  when 'Machine3' then 'Development'
  when 'Machine6' then 'Development'
  else 'Stage enviroment' 
end as Category

Comment: Is there another alternative? What if I have like 100 MachineNames that I need to categorize?

Comment: You really need to add the categories to the database. Unless we're missing something here, then there is no way to know what category a machine belongs to. If you ever did a similar query in the future you would have to repeat all the logic. Seriously consider adding it to the database.

Comment: @Alan is right you should add it into your database. One last thing you can do (when you cant access the database) is, that you add your category in a calculated field to your dataset `=IIF(Fields!YourValues.Value = "1", "Category1", "CategoryElse")`. This way its not in your database but you can copy and paste the logic if you want to use it again.

Answer (score 0):

you can sort  by machine name and add a row number

then you got something like this

machine1 1
machine2 2
machine3 3
machine4 4
machine5 5
machine6 6
machine7 7
machine8 8
machine9 9

and finaly you add a case in your select

(case when ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY "machine name" ) < 5 then 'Production'
else (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY "machine name" ASC) > 5 and ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY "machine name" ASC) < 7) then 'Development' else 'Stage' end ) as groupName